# Sync old mails with Einstein Activity Capture

Tags: email, einstein, sync, activity

I just set up a completely fresh org. I'm using Einstein Einstein Activity Capture to sync mails from Gsuite to Salesforce.

However, this only works for emails sent/received after setting up the Org. Any chance to go back at least a little bit e.g. 60 days and sync these older mails as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works natively out of the box.

I'm an idiot. Should anyone else ever happen to struggle with this as well: all you need to do is wait, for a very long time though (can take 1-2 days).